# Solr - Make on character search for several others

Tags: solr

I'm currently trying to make Solr index a lot of library data. This library data for example contains authors spelled differently, and with local letters (such as ä, ü, ø, ö, etc). I'd like it to be possible for my users to search for `Østersøen` and get results such as `Österssöen, Østersøen`.

My question is, how do I achieve this with Solr. It seems to me that mappings won't cut it, since I'd like *one* character to be able to count as several others.

```
u -> u, ü, ù, ú
å -> å, aa
ø -> ø, ö, o
```

but **also** the other way around (with some of them), so that

```
aa -> å
```

Is this possible, and if so how?

Answer (score 1):

Look at the tips [here](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/LanguageAnalysis#Ignoring_Diacritics). Basically there are two things to do:

1. proper stemming/filters depending on the language
2. ASCIIFoldingFilterFactory/ICUFoldingFilterFactory

Answer (score 0):

You want Unicode folding (ICUFoldingFilterFactory), which does all the normalization.

You also want to read through [the whole 12 post series on the using Solr in the library](http://discovery-grindstone.blogspot.com/2013/10/cjk-with-solr-for-libraries-part-1.html) with CJK issues as a focus. It will probably answer the questions you don't even have yet. Finally, if you haven't looked at [Project Blacklight](http://projectblacklight.org/) yet, it is worth doing so. It's a community of people using Solr specifically for libraries and they may have common problems and solutions.